# how to access google define feature in a batch

Tags: linux, google-app-engine

Suppose I have a huge set of noisy phrases. For each one of them, I want to check if it is defined by some resources by using the google define feature. Once I type "define my_phrase" to the google search box, if the retrieved results contain the definition panel (e.g. https://www.google.com/#q=define+home+cooking), I put it into my phrase pool.

I'm wondering is this possible to do this task in a batch so that I don't have to type each of the phrase manually one by one? It would be great if this could be achieved from a unix terminal but windows is also welcome!

I heard of google-app-engine but I only have a rough idea and not sure if it could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as starting point, you may try and play with the Google Custom search following API reference - Xml results
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en&csw=1#XML_Results

Be aware of:

- google TOS for this service
- quantity courtesy limit